# My image and my iframe video fall outside of my jumbotron when I resize them to the smaller size. How do I prevent this?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Everything seems to be positioned where I want it but the image and video will overlap the jumbotron on the smaller size. I have checked other posts and have not found anything useful to answer my question. I should clarify that it comes out at the right side of the jumbotron.

```css
<style>
    body {
    margin: 20px;
}
    #img_position {
    position: relative;
            left: 14%;
            padding: 15px;
        max-width: 100%;
            }

            #jumbo
            {
            background-color: #bfff80;
            font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
                min-width: 100%;
            }
    .gw_vid{
        position:relative;
        padding-top:5%;
        max-width:32%;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
            </style>
```

```html
        <div class="container box ">
            <div id="jumbo" class="jumbotron box">
            <h1 style="text-align: center">George Washington</h1>
                <h4 style="text-align:center">The first President of the Untited States of America</h4>
                <img id="img_position" src="http://projectmanagementhacks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/George-Washington-Success-Principles.jpg">
                <div class="gw_vid">
                <iframe width="350px" height="350px"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/thin1LeCrxY" target="blank"></iframe>
            </iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I added col-md-12 to my picture and that resolved that issue for now but I tried the col-md-12 with the video and got no good results.
Any help with the video issue would be great.

Comment: I have tried max-height, min-height, min-width and max-width on the img, video and the jumbotron. Nothing works. I have tried everything up to the point I posted this question. You can see my code and tell me if there is something wrong.

Comment: Is there a reason for changing the height when it is the width I am having a problem with?

Comment: You should take a look at the 'img-responsive' class for bootstrap. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images. Also, your custom css on the video and img elements seem to be causing some of your issues -- If you want to have left/right padding on your image, I'd look into 'border-box' box sizing so that it's included in the width.

Comment: Here's a jsbin of some of what I mean (also the responsive video embedding of bootstrap) https://jsbin.com/ninifugaqe/edit?html

Comment: I have removed all of the dimensions for the video and had it at its smallest size without the dimensions and I still have the same issue. I think I need to work on the size of the jumbotron. I re-positioned my picture since it was not centered correctly and it at least stays within the jumbotron but not centered.

Answer (score 0):

I put your code into Codepen and It told me i don't need  tags, first of all after i took out the style tags i ran the code and it looks perfectly fine. I beleive solution here is to create a new file for the CSS then link them in the head. If you don't know how to do that, here is the code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nameoffyourfile.css"


        **HTML**
<div class="container box ">
<div id="jumbo" class="jumbotron box">
<h1 style="text-align: center">George Washington</h1>
<h4 style="text-align:center">The first President of the Untited States of 
America</h4>
<img id="img_position" src="http://projectmanagementhacks.com/wp-
content/uploads/2015/03/George-Washington-Success-Principles.jpg">
<div class="gw_vid">
  <iframe width="350px" height="350px" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/thin1LeCrxY" target="blank"></iframe>
  </iframe>
</div>
</div>

  **CSS**

body {
margin: 20px;
}

#img_position {
position: relative;
left: 14%;
padding: 15px;
max-width: 100%;
}

#jumbo {
background-color: #bfff80;
font-family: 'Cinzel', serif;
min-width: 100%;
}

.gw_vid {
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 5%;
 max-width: 32%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

Comment: yes, I keep my style sheets, head and html all separate when I do my code. I will run your code. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Bootstrap, you can use the native responsive embed for your YouTube video: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed

Comment: Thanks Phillip. I have been banging my head on a wall trying to figure out what to do. That worked perfectly.